# How to find and aggregate observations that replaced others in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, recursion, logic, aggregation

Context:

- A sales partner registers an opportunity (OppID) and it expires in 180 days if not closed;
- When it expires, the same sales partner registers a new OppID, but it is actually a continuation of the past OppID;
- There is a reference for the past OppID, in a manual free text field (Notes), with strings like "Replaces ";

Sample Dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(OppID=c("A123","A765","B456","C137","F879","H987"),OppDate=c("1/20/2020","1/21/2020","7/21/2020","1/4/2020","11/1/2020","8/21/2020"),OppStatus=c("Closed","Closed","Open","Closed","Open","Closed"),Notes=c("","","Replaces A123","","Replaces B456","Replaces A765"))
```

This is the resulting dataframe (df):

```
  head(df)
  OppID OppDate   OppStatus Notes
1 A123  1/20/2020 Closed    
2 A765  1/21/2020 Closed   
3 B456  7/21/2020 Open      Refers to A123
4 C137  1/4/2020  Closed    
5 F879  11/1/2020 Open      Refers to B456
6 H987  8/21/2020 Open      Refers to A765
```

What I need to accomplish - programmatically - is something like this (a new dataframe 'df2'):

```
  head(df2)
  OppID OppDate   OppStatus Notes               FirstOppDate
1 C137  1/4/2020  Closed    
2 F879  11/1/2020 Open      Refers to A123,B456 1/20/2020
3 H987  8/21/2020 Open      Refers to A765      1/21/2020
```

As you can see in df2, OppID A123 and B456 should move to OppID F879 (as F879 is a continuation of B456, and B456 is a continuation of A123). A new column should be created to record the OppDate from the oldest OppID (in this case A123 back in 1/20/2020).

A similar situation happens to H987 (continuation of A765). Finally, C137 didn't change as this OppID isn't a continuation of any prior OppID.

I tried to figure out a way to do that, but no success so far. I know how to extract the OppID from the free text field, but can't think about a way to check this relationships and aggregate it in the newest OppID.

Any ideas? I hope it makes sense what I want to achieve (not a native English speaker). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['OppID', 'OppDate', 'OppStatus', 'Notes']
rows = [['A123', '1/20/2020', 'Closed' ,''], 
        ['A765', '1/21/2020', 'Closed', ''],
       ['B456', '7/21/2020', 'Open', 'Refers to A123'], 
       ['C137', '1/4/2020' , 'Closed', ''],
       ['F879', '11/1/2020', 'Open' ,'Refers to B456'],
       ['H987', '8/21/2020', 'Open', 'Refers to A765']]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = columns)

# You can use a regular expression that suits better
df['ref_opp_id'] = [x.split()[-1] if len(x)>0 else None for x in df['Notes']] 

# This can be parallelized or can be further optimized
total_ref_opps = []
first_opp_dates = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    total = []
    final_opp_id = row['ref_opp_id']
    first_opp_date = None
    while final_opp_id is not None:
        total.append(final_opp_id)
        first_opp_date = df[df['OppID'] == final_opp_id]['OppDate'].values[0]
        final_opp_id = df[df['OppID'] == final_opp_id]['ref_opp_id'].values[0]
    total_ref_opps.append(total)
    first_opp_dates.append(first_opp_date)

df['total_ref_opps'] = total_ref_opps
df['first_opp_dates'] = first_opp_dates

all_dup_items = [item for sublist in total_ref_opps for item in sublist]

df_new = df[~df['OppID'].isin(all_dup_items)].copy().reset_index(drop=True)

df_new.head()
```

I am a new contributor. Please mark this answer as successful if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: Thanks @con, I will definitely keep that in mind for my following answers.

Comment: Wonderful @KRISHNAMALLIK. It worked exactly as I needed. Thanks a lot!